# Training tensorflow detection api on colaboratory

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to train tensorflow object detection api on colaboratory.

When I run train.py as '%run train.py ...'  I receive the error 'Duplicate flag error: the flag 'master' is defined twice.

When I run train.py as '!python train.py ...' I receive the error 'no module named deployment'.

I have set the path using: 
import sys

```
sys.path.append('/content/models/research/slim')
sys.path.append('/content/models/research')
sys.path.append('/content/models/research/object_detection')
```

In addition I am running train from the object_detection directory. I'm not sure what else I need to do to run the train.py script successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below snippet is for setting up the tensorflow object detection api on colab specifically.

`

```
!apt-get install protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml python-tk
!pip install Cython
!pip install jupyter
!pip install matplotlib

!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

%cd /content/models/research

!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

%set_env PYTHONPATH=/content/models/research:/content/models/research/slim

!python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
```

`

On google colab, the above series of lines need to be executed in order to have your object detection api up and running.
The actual details for installation are found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md)

The below line specifies how to run the train script

```
%run object_detection/train.py \
    --logtostderr \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PATH_TO_YOUR_PIPELINE_CONFIG} \
    --train_dir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR}
```

From the official documentation, all these scripts are run from within the

> /models/research

directory. Not from within the object detection folder itself.